# Problem running overpass web api

Tags: overpass-api

I have installed overpass api on debian following [install wiki page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/install) every thing is ok before starting the web api, when I start dispatcher daemon, It starts with no error and apache2 is started correctly but /api/interpreter is not found!404 Not Found, according to wiki page I tried :

sudo a2enmod cgi

but it says:

"Your MPM seems to be threaded. Selecting cgid instead of cgi."

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 1):

After one day I finally could solve the problem, I just changed default file in site-available to default.conf and with a2ensite enabled that and in the other hand, in site-enabled with a2dissite disabled 0000-default file.